# Passing form data from EJS to Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am creating a web application in Node running over an Express server.
I have EJS files as my views and Javascript ones as my brains feeding the view.

I am trying to get the value of a dropdown that the user selects in the view and pass it back to the Javascript to be used as a parameter in a function:

**index.ejs**

```
<form>
  <select id="projDrop">
      <% var eachProject = projects.split('|'); %>
      <% for (var i = 1; i < projNo + 1; i++) { %>
      <option value="<%= eachProject[i]; %>"><%= eachProject[i]; %></option>
      <% } %>
  </select>
  <select id="filtDrop">
      <% var eachFilter = filters.split('|'); %>
      <% for (var i = 1; i < filtNo + 1; i++) { %>
        <option value="<%= eachFilter[i]; %>"><%= eachFilter[i]; %></option>
      <% } %>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="jira.searchJira('filter = ' + document.getElementById('filtDrop').value + ''
  , results, function(error, data){})" />
</form>
```

**index.js**

```
jira.searchJira('filter = "???????"', results, function(error, data) {      //search for saved filter
    if (error) {
        next(new Error(error));
    }
    allIssues = data.issues;                                               //stores all issues
});
```

My dropdowns are in a form. I want the value of the dropdown to be the argument `('filter = "???????"', ...` in the parameter listings of that function. As you can see, I've attempted it where you can see `onclick()` in the EJS file by `document.getElementById()` but this does not return anything I think because the function I'm trying to call if not in the EJS file.

I know it's possible for the JS to talk to the EJS but I want to see if it's possible to do it the other way around.